# SELinux port type to reserve port for user PHP in-built webserver

Tags: php, selinux, users

I am trying to get an application running which uses the PHP inbuilt webserver. It gives permission denied because of SELinux running on the system. There is no policy for the PHP inbuilt webserver as far as I know when ordinary users run one.

This is the output and example of what I want to be able to do...

```
$ php -S localhost:32322
[Sun Jan  5 04:38:24 2020] Failed to listen on localhost:32322 (reason: Permission denied)
```

I have been looking and searching on Google but I cannot find a port type which will let this work.

The user running the PHP webserver is in the `user_u` context.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the policy details it will be hard to answer your question correctly. It is likely that the requested action might need a special/custom SELinux module.

Eventually, the boolean `selinuxuser_tcp_server` can help you to solve your issue.

On Fedora 31 it looks like it does what you require:
https://github.com/fedora-selinux/selinux-policy/blob/f31/policy/modules/system/userdomain.if#L1477-L1479

```
    tunable_policy(`selinuxuser_tcp_server',`
        corenet_tcp_bind_all_unreserved_ports($1_usertype)
    ')
```

On Fedora 31 with `targeted` policy the port is not registered/used.

```
# semanage port -l | grep unreserved
unreserved_port_t              sctp     1024-65535
unreserved_port_t              tcp      61001-65535, 1024-32767
unreserved_port_t              udp      61001-65535, 1024-32767
# semanage port -l | grep 3022
#
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add more details with logs to prove it is Selinux issue, however since you are assuring with question it is selinux linux so you can try below:

Check port is allowed or not

```
semanage port -l | grep http 
Or 
sepolicy network -t http_port_t
```

You also check in alert, it will suggest you want command you need to run to allow permission.

```
sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

One example to allow port

```
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 32322
```

Add more details if solution not works for you, so I can add more solution.

Comment: The answer is likely partially correct. Still I do think it won't work, as it was described that the process is running as `user_u` context. Your description describes to enable the port for `http_port_t` type, which is likely not a type `user_u` has permission to bind.